# Where is settings.py supposed to be with Eve?

Tags: flask, eve

I keep getting an exception stating

```
DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.
```

My folder structure looks like this

```
.
└──myapp
   ├── app.py
   ├── app.wsgi
   └── settings.py
```

So Eve is stating that Dictionary cannot be found, even though it's defined in the settings file.   I'm running this app in a virtualenv and I have my apache virtual host pointed to the wsgi file.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/RedTurtle/eve-sqlalchemy/issues/15) thread?

Comment: yeah, it didn't help me much unfortunately.

Comment: Is Eve picking up the other settings in your settings.py? Maybe try with passing an explicit settings file and see if anything changes?

Answer (score 1):

Hit this too, and after a bit of rooting around this is the conclusion I've reached.

Eve has, to me, an unintuitive method of finding the settings file. You can see it [in the code](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/blob/master/eve/flaskapp.py#L202). It does the following:

1. Gets the name of the settings file from the environment variable `'EVE_SETTINGS'` if set, otherwise from the string passed as the `settings=` key-word argument to the `Eve()` constructor, default `'settings.py'`.
2. Looks in the directory of `sys.argv[0]` to see if the file is there. It seems odd to me that this is useful enough to be the first option.
3. **Walks every directory in `sys.path` to try and find a settings file.** Which means if any module you have installed in your environment has a file named `settings.py` anywhere in it, Eve will try to use that.
4. If Eve doesn't find one, then it doesn't use one.

So, my problem was that I was running Eve from a virtualenv that also had django installed. Django has (at least one) sample `'settings.py'` file in it. So Eve was trying to use that. And it was crashing. Thanks Eve.

Also note that it doesn't look in the current directory for a settings file at all (unless it's in your `PYTHONPATH`). This seems a bit nuts to me.

I have raised [an issue](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/1023) on Eve's github page.

Comment: Just to say that this answer has probably nothing to do with original question which was asked 2 years ago because this particular code changed a lot in the meantime. Please join the discussion on [the issue you created](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/1023) and also read a bit about [Flask Application Dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appdispatch/) to get the idea how to run Flask and Django together.

Comment: I'll just add: 3a. It assumes the first file named 'settings.py' in root directory of the first loaded module that contains such a file, not in sub paths (that is what I observe).